# Where to find my user data dump?

Tags: support, personal-data

A while back (2 months ago or so), I found a JSON data dump of Stackoverflow's analysis of me as a user. It included information as to how the site perceived me based on my activity (ie. full-stack programmer).

I'm unsure if I found this data as a result of the 2015 survey, my SO profile, or my SO Careers profile.

Does this sound familiar to anyone? Does anyone know where I can find this data again?

Comment: Hijack: Is there anything like this that has all my activity in a dump, not just SO's predictions based on my activity? Just curious.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen Besides the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries), I don't think so. (It's easy enough to get all Questions, Answers or Comments for yourself from the Data Explorer, though you'd have to do them separately).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're looking for the [Your Personalized Prediction Data](https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data) page:

[image]

You can get to it by going to the `Edit Profile and Settings` tab on your profile, then `Preferences`, then the `Manage personalized predictions` link at the bottom of the page.

(You might also be interested in [my web application for uploading and visualizing the results](http://varianceexplained.org/r/providence-visualizer/)):

[image]